# Optimizing data driven web application

Tags: hibernate, design-patterns, ehcache, nosql

I've built a simple web application using Java Server Faces (JSF) where I have a web page with a link and when I click that link, I just go to the database(MySQL) and fetch a list of items and would display in the web page. I've used Hibernate as an ORM tool.

I just have total of 10-15 entries in the database table that I query and the hibernate query is like "from myObject" which returns all the entries in the table.

Now, I'm trying to improve the performance of this application by limiting the number of queries to the database on every click on that link.

So I started learning about hibernate first level caching, second level caching, and Ehcache. Now I've some basic understanding on how they work.

Here is my question

Question : Let's say that the users of this application are divided into n groups-g1,g2,...,gn and each group has m users. When a user from group g1 clicks that link, I want to show a list of items specific to that particular group g1. Basically I want to show different list of items for different groups of users when they click on the link in the web page. As I want to show the same list of items to users in the same group, **I want to limit the calls to database when the users from same group click that link**. It would be great if some one could give their suggestions or give me some pointers that would help me go forward.

It is the same object that holds the data shown for all the user groups. There are adds, updates, and deletes to Entries(list of items shown in the web page) in the database. The list of items shown to the user is not static.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to cache the results and return it based on the check on the current user. This could be done in a simple manner using a map in a java class.

Comment: So when I consistently add, update and delete the items, wouldn't the cache become stale? If I use some data structure like a map and put in application scope and keep the latest data in that map(just keep updating the map when ever a add, edit or delete happens) and just return that map when a user clicks on that link, if the number of groups are large the map size may grow larger (which might use some considerable amount of IN MEMORY) and definitely it might be not a good idea to have a different map for a different group where the group number is large. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The caching you wanna implement has a business rule attached to it. My take is that you may have to handle it at business layer. Agreed that it wouldn't be a simple map as there are frequent writes to the underlying data. This Domain Store pattern [http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/DomainStore.htm] might be of help. You may have to implement a state manger to maintain the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I started using redis which actually serves my purpose. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888880/what-is-redis-and-what-do-i-use-it-for) explains redis and its uses.